# about closures and function scope

Tags: javascript

I'm reading a chapter of a book dealing with closures and scoping.

Let's start from two examples (I copy them from the book). Consider the following code:

```
var scope = "global space";
function checkscope(){
  var scope ="local scope";
  function f() { return scope; }
  return f();
}
checkscope();
```

here the value that we obtain calling checkscope() function is "local scope".

Now, consider this function:

```
var scope = "global space";
function checkscope(){
  var scope ="local scope";
  function f() { return scope; }
  return f;
}
checkscope()();
```

It seems similar but it isn't, we have `return f` rather than `return f()` inside `checkscope function` and `checkscope` itself is called at the end with two pairs of parentheses rather than one couple.

Could you help me to understand these two variations? I don't understand why f function is called without parentheses: it's a function, if you want to call it you need to use the parentheses, I guess. Then, about checkscope function, why all those parentheses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't understand why f function is called without parentheses: it's a function, if you want to call it you need to use the parentheses, I guess. Then, about checkscope function, why all those parentheses?

It is *not* called without parenthesis. In JavaScript, functions are first-class values, and you can just refer to them and return them as objects, without calling them. This is what happens here. Calling `checkscope` does return a function which you then have to call for accessing `scope`:

```
var ref_to_f = checkscope(); // the function f() { return scope; }
ref_to_f(); // "local scope"
```

This is what actually makes closures interesting - you can call a function that has access to a different scope than you (the caller) have.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the variation of `checkscope`, you see this:

```
return f;
```

It is returning the actual function object; it is not calling the function. In JavaScript, functions are objects just like any other object, like a string.

If you paste this code into the console, and type `checkscope()`, you will see the return value of `function f() { return scope; }`. See, it's returning the actual function object, because it's not being called (with `()`).

So then, when you do `checkscope()()`, you are calling `checkscope()` (which returns a function) and then calling that function that it returns with another `()`.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example `checkscope` returns the result of function `f`, while in the second it returns a reference to function `f` which is then called in the global scope: `checkscope()();` (note the second pare of parentheses).